# bootstrap touchspin - input type not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this Bootstrap touchspinner that I only want people to enter numbers into (decimals/ints/floats etc)

HTML:

```
<input id="customValSpinner" type="number" value="" name="customValSpinner" class="inline"/>
```

JS:

```
$("input[name='customValSpinner']").TouchSpin({
    min: 0,
    max: 9000,
    step: 0.1,
    decimals: 1,
    boostat: 5,
    maxboostedstep: 10,
    postfix: "ft"
});
```

The problem is - people can still type numbers into the text box. They can't enter them but the client wants me to make it to where they can't even type them in. Also, they want to be able to type in the textbox, so I can't make it readonly.

I have already tried triggering the on change event but this only fires when using the bootstrap increment buttons.(+,-)

Bootstrap Touchspin:
http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-touchspin/

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.